# How to use ALERTIFY JS in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert, alertify

I'm trying to use ALERTIFYJS in react but its alertify alerts are not working. Below is the code

(window.alert is working fine on my browser)

```
import alertify from 'alertifyjs';

clickHandle = () => {
  alertify.alert('Alert Title', 'Alert Message!', function(){ 
    alertify.success('Ok'); 
  });
}
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @ArupRakshit alertify alerts

Comment: Any errors in the console that might give you a hint on why it's not working?

Comment: no errors even in console its showing everything ok.
if i console alertify its show there is a function alert

Comment: You should add the css file tooo

Comment: @sultanaslam how you have alertify styles in react?

Comment: @AshishSharma  add the alertify css file too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Need to add the css file too. Problem Solved.

```
import 'alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.css';
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You have to add css file as well.

Here is the process for adding css and importing alertify

```
import alertify from 'alertifyjs';
import 'alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.css';
```

or

```
import * as alertify from 'alertifyjs';
import 'alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.css';
```

Please note I have tested this code on react js 16.13.1 with restify 1.13.1